# How to run multiple event handlers asynchronously in c# console application

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm writing a c# console application using .net 4.7.1. I have two directories I want to monitor and run some code whenever a file is created in either directory, so I believe that what I need to do is to create two separate event handlers, one to watch each directory. Here's my code I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunMultiHandlers()
}

private static void RunMultiHandlers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Combined 1");
    string strRunDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 2");        
    string strWatchPath850s = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\850s";
    string strWatchPath855s = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\855s";

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 3");    
    FileSystemWatcher watcher850s = new FileSystemWatcher();

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 4");        
    watcher850s.Path = strWatchPath850s;

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 5");        
    watcher850s.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((sender, e) => OnChanged("850s"));

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 6");        
    watcher850s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 7");        
    FileSystemWatcher watcher855s = new FileSystemWatcher();

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 8");    
    watcher850s.Path = strWatchPath855s;

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 9");        
    watcher850s.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((sender, e) => OnChanged("855s"));

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 10");       
    watcher850s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Combined 11");    
    while (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") == strRunDate) ;   
}

private static async Task OnChanged(string strCaller)
{
    Console.WriteLine("caller " + strCaller);
}
```

When I run this code the messages "Combined 1" through "Combined 11" are displayed to the console, so it appears that my event handlers are created successfully. However, when I create a file in the `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\850s` directory nothing is output to the console. When I create a file in `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\855s` the messages

> caller 850s

and

> caller 855s

are output to the console. What I want to have happen is when a file is created in the `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\850s` directory the message

> caller 850s

should output to the console and when I create a file in the `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\850s` directory the message

> caller 855s

should output to the console. If anyone would give me some direction as to what needs to change with my code to accomplish these desired results I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last `while` loop may want a sleep in it, to not hammer the CPU.

Comment: Its just a simple typo, everywhere you use `watcher850s` below Combined 8 needs to be `watcher855s`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sometimes the most simple answer is what trips me up. That's exactly the problem. Fixed it and it now runs exactly as expected. If you post an answer I'll accept it and give you an up vote. Thank you very much.